# WordPress 5.5.3. Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _wp_register_meta_args_whitelist() (previously declared in …\wp-includes\meta.php:1409) in …\wp-include

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently started to get the same exact error regularly. First I got the error (`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _wp_register_meta_args_whitelist() (previously declared in …\wp-includes\meta.php:1409) in …\wp-includes\deprecated.php on line 4064`), I manually update to **WordPress 5.5.3**. And it resolved the problem. Then I updated to plugins when I able to reach admin panel.

Next day, I faced up with the same error. Again I deleted `wp-includes` and `wp-admin`. Paste freshly downloaded `wp-includes` and `wp-admin`. Overwrite existing files on `wp-content`. Then the error disappeared again. I went to admin panel to update the plugins.

Today I woke up and see that I have same error. I just deleted `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` and uploaded them, and problem is gone again but I’m worried about to get same error tomorrow. Is anyone having the same problem?

Hosting *WordPress 5.5.3 Turkish* version in *Windows Server*. Running *PHP version: 7.2.26*.
Active plugins:

- [Simple Custom CSS and JS 3.34](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)
- [Elementor 3.0.13](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementor/)
- [One Click Demo Import 2.6.1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-click-demo-import/)
- [Redirection 4.9.2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)
- [TopBar Call To Action 1.0.9](https://wordpress.org/plugins/topbar-call-to-action/)
- [Yoast SEO 15.2.1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)
- [Display PHP Version 1.5](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-php-version/)
- [Akismet Anti-Spam 4.1.7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/)

And the lines on the error(the version that before I delete the wp-includes and upload new version):

**…\wp-includes\meta.php**:*1409*

```
function _wp_register_meta_args_whitelist( $args, $default_args ) {
    return array_intersect_key( $args, $default_args );
}
```

**…\wp-includes\deprecated.php**:*4064*

```
function _wp_register_meta_args_whitelist( $args, $default_args ) {
    _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '5.5.0', '_wp_register_meta_args_allowed_list()' );

    return _wp_register_meta_args_allowed_list( $args, $default_args );
}
```

Comment: In WordPress version 5.5, line [1409 of meta.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5-branch/wp-includes/meta.php#L1409) doesn't look like that, and in fact that function was removed in version 5.5 (or moved to deprecated, technically). If that function appears in meta.php, then you aren't on the complete 5.5 branch. Either you are coping from an older WordPress, or something on the system is overwriting your changes. I recommend this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/), where you can use the Tools tab to looks for incorrect files for your current version.

Comment: @ChrisHaas That's the problem. Although I delete all the files and folders from `wp-includes` (_including meta.php_) and upload the newest `wp-includes`, somehow it turn back to old `wp-includes/meta.php` after a while. Today I just replaced the `meta.php` and it worked, no need to delete and upload whole `wp-includes` and `wp-admin`. But I'm sure that it will change again to old `meta.php` after a while.

Comment: There's a small chance you have some bad code on your site that is doing this, but I would highly doubt it. Instead, I would coordinate with your host. If you are in a managed WP environment, it is possible that their system is hard-locking you to a certain version and "fixing" things. You should take a note of the file creation and modification times, too, both when you make a change as well as when you notice a change. If the changed version's timestamp is near an hour mark (2:00, 6:00, etc.), they would further enforce that it is probably an automated thing.